# I am facing problem of cuted.sty not found in texmaker. how to resolve the issue?

Tags: cuted

[image: image shows error]I am facing problem of `package expl3 required` not found in `texmaker`, how to resolve the issue?

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mathtools}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Texmaker has nothing to do with this, it's just a dedicated editor. Probably it isnt installed. What is your distribution?

Comment: @Bernard Actually,  my TEXmaker is facing 13backbend pdf not found. I have updated FNDB but nothing happened. Kindly help me what to do?

Comment: Are you using MiKTeX or TeX Live?

Comment: @Bernard MikTeX. Now I have updated 13kernel and facing error "package expl3 required". What to do with it. I have not found expl3 in miktex pkg manager.

Comment: But `expl3` is a component of the (MiKTeX) package `l3kernel`!?? As to `cuted`,  it comes with the `sttools` bundle.

Comment: @Bernard Sir, I have edited question and attach the image of error. Kindly help

Comment: Could you post a small *compilable* code reproducing the error?

Comment: are you asking about cuted or expl3 you seem to be asking about both at the same time

Comment: @Bernard Sir, my pdf is fine, lipsum is work instead of this error. thanks for ur time

Comment: l3backend is a new package. To get miktex to install it you should update the package database in the miktex console.